# How to express 'Thumbs Up/Down' in a word or two?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

Emojies have made our lives easier than ever before. We save a lot of time in writing words and expressing ourselves. But then, at times we need to 'write' our expression due to limitations of software.

I want no 'personalized' message. Said that, 'Agreed' does not sound typically 'Thumbs Up'. The charm, motivation and agreement 'thumbs up' has lacks in 'Agreed'. On the other hand, expressing 'Thumbs Down' in words is even complex. If there are many options, I'll be happy to have them all to use it in different conversations.

*'Kudos!'* is something I can think of for 'Thumbs Up', but more such words will be appreciated. Also, what is the opposite to *Kudos!* in one or two word?

Comment: Whydoeseverythinghavetobeoneword?

Comment: @DavidRicherby hahaha...good one! :) But I'm not searching for a sentence where I can express a lot of things! :) I'm in search of a word and not a phrase. Otherwise, I can say, *"Yes, this seems to be a great idea. I agree with this and you did a good job!"* -too tired to type it ;)

Comment: Sure but you could just type "Thumbs up!" The space bar is big and easy to find. :-) I think your question is interesting, even though I feel that, like most single word requests, it's based on a bit of a false premise.

Comment: Wouldn't  someone (or someon's action) worth a "Thumbs Up" -Emoji be worth two words? I can think of On-word-substitutes for "Thumbs Down", but they are not necessarily nice. Just one example, in honour of Christmas: "Humbug!"

Comment: Nah, nope, no, wrong, sorry, and one from the twenties: Fuhgettaboutit

Comment: Demanding a single word for something is not reasonable; see [this meta question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/should-we-be-closing-single-word-requests). Many ideas in English are not expressible in a single word. There's nothing wrong with *thumbs up / thumbs down*; these short phrases are perfectly succinct.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Kudos is a single word and perfectly fits to 'Thumbs up'. I confirmed. If not single word, two words are okay but the crux is, I'm not asking for the phrase.

Comment: It’s going to depend on the context. A thumbs-up might be saying "okay", "got it", "good for you", "message received", "yes", or many other things.

Comment: @MaulikV *kudos* does **not** mean the same as *thumbs up*. What is wrong with just saying *thumbs up / down*? Are you asking for synonyms (which would be off topic; it's a thesaurus reference)? Are you asking for a single word only (which you say you aren't, but still seems like you are, and should also be off topic)? What particular meaning of *thumbs up* are you using (there are many; needs more context)? Without further clarification, I can't see how your question is on topic (which in itself is reason enough to VTC as unclear).

Comment: @EsotericScreenName not only did I mention the context, but I also explained the reason (of software limitations). Tell me, where do you 'select' Thumbs Up sign on Skype? Those are the contexts for a word of two I'm asking. Tell me further, where do you 'select' Thumbs Down from an [emoji](http://getemoji.com/) gallery? Those are the contexts, I'm asking for the word thumbs down. Imagine there's no such emojies. How do you express it in your words. Hope it's clear now

Comment: Isn't *Thumbs Up* "a word or two"?

Answer (score 1):

" Approved! / Disapproved! " looks like a fair candidate to me.

Comment: This seems more authoritative. Though no downvote.